# jQuery breaks PrestaShop

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I want to insert google content experiments code to PrestaShop. When I load this file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as script to `header.tpl` of ganalytics module (first line, or any line), prestashop layout breaks.

We have basic template and prestashop 1.5.0. Please, can you point me to the problem? I can't leave the site there but I took screenshot of broken version here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUCJC.png

You can see the website on http://tinyurl.com/qcgf4va

Comment: im not familiar with prestashop but it could be conflicting with the $ have you tried the noConflict option for jQuery?

Comment: @workabyte I am confused. Should I somehow set this noConflict up in prestashop? I tried creating override for Controller.php with this code: http://www.sourcepod.com/tecxoa69-33008 but it also broke my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prestashop has a method for using jQuery. Quoting from [their docs](http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11272250):

> ## About Controller::addJquery()
>
> When this method is called with a parameter, it includes the current version of jQuery, as available in
>   the PrestaShop installation. For instance, this method can be called
>   from the `setMedia()` method in the `AdminController`:
>
> ```
> public function setMedia() {
>     $this->addJquery();
> }
> ```

and

> Version 1.3.1 of jQuery is not available through `$`, but rather using
>   the `$j131` variable. Hence, you can call `$j131('body').hide();`. If
>   you wish to use 1.3.1's `$`, you simply have to use this:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var tmp = $;     // jQuery's current version becomes en temporary variable.
> $ = $j131;
> $('body').hide(); // Now using 1.3.1's hide().
> $ = tmp;          // IMPORTANT: always restore the default version of jQuery!
> </script>
> ```
>
> If the file is on your server, you can give its path as a second
>   argument: `Controller::addJquery('1.3.1', '/local/path/to/jquery');`

Comment: Hi, so your hypothesis is that for my content experiments needs, the 131 is going to be sufficient?

Comment: I would not use jQuery 1.3.1 in production; [it was released over 5 years ago](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/01/21/jquery-131-released/). The quote from the docs shows you how to use any version of jQuery.

Comment: Is there a way to tell prestashop to call 2.0.0 by $j200 and the rest would be 1.3.1 ? I did not use it. It was packaged in Prestashop. I want to implement the 2.0.0 because of google content experimente :-(

Comment: I would use `Controller::addJquery('2.0.0', '/local/path/to/jquery.min.js');`. I'm not sure if using your own copy of jQuery will use `$` or $j200`.